# MVC - what are the benefits of all controller actions being Task<ActionResult>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I've been using MVC since version 2, and lately I have come across a project where all of the controller actions are 'async', returning Tasks, and I am trying to understand why somebody would do this.

The View Model for each view is built via an async call to an API. I understand that in order to use the await keyword one must use an async method (and return a Task), but surely without the View Model then the view will fail. There is no choice but to wait for the API to build my View Model.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyCar()
    {
        return View(await MyAPI.BuildMyCarViewModel());
    }
```

For what reason would controller actions need to be asynchronous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that your part of code

```
MyAPI.BuildMyCarViewModel()
```

needs for execution 15 seconds. 
 Then let's assume, that you have 10 000 users, which in range of 2 seconds decided to load some model.
 And then assume that you don't use caching ( for the sake of example ).
IIS by default has pool of threads 5000.
In described case application pool of IIS will be busy with 5000 threads which will translate into awaiting of your 5000 users for 5 seconds, and other 5000 users will wait until code finish executing. But with async/await .Net will generate state machine, and threads will be executed till moment of awaiting, and then threads will be released for making another useful job. And as soon as

```
MyAPI.BuildMyCarViewModel()
```

will return results, other threads or the same threads will return you result. And as outcome application pool of IIS will not be exhausted quickly for long running tasks and your users will receive response much faster, then without usage await/async. 
 If to put simply, await/async gives you possibility to avoid thread pool exhausting quickly for long running fragments of code.

Comment: Ok but isn't the user forced to sit and wait for those 15 seconds, because the View needs the ViewModel before it can render?

Comment: Yes, user will be forced to sit and wait for 15 seconds. But without async/await only first 5000 users will wait 15 seconds + response time. Other users will sit and wait for freeing resource by lucky users + 15 seconds of their awaiting time. While with async/await all users have chances to be served in range 15 seconds + synchronization of responses + response time. And take notice, that you don't need to have headache with synchronization.

Comment: So what you're saying is... IF my ViewModel is built by a method that takes a long time, and IF I have lots of users, then an async controller action makes sense. Otherwise there is no point?

Comment: If to see the world only from those two points ( many users, slow execution of method )  you understand everything correctly. But I propose you to take into account one more point. It doesn't take a lot of efforts to make your controller ready for many users and for long time processing. So to say to prepare your code in advance. So if it doesn't take a lot of mental powers to apply async/await construction, then why not use them?

Comment: Does it make sense our you want to know more reasons?

Answer (score 1):

I have an MSDN article on the topic of [`async` ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx). In summary, the benefit is that the request does not take up a thread for the duration of the request. This allows your web app to scale if your backend can scale.

Comment: Are you able to give me an example of when you would need your controller actions, that return Views, to be async. I can only think if you have some methods inside that take a lot of time to execute and you want to free up the server to be able to process other requests.
But then, I would only have a few Actions as async. Not all.

Comment: @VictorySaber: It's not really a question of returning views - it's a question of what the action has to do to create the models that are passed to the views. Any I/O to a scalable backend is a good candidate for asynchronous actions. So, if your backend is Azure Tables/Blobs or Azure SQL or MongoDB or some cloud API, then you would definitely want those actions async. If your backend isn't scalable (i.e., a single instance of SQL Server), then there's (probably) no point in making those actions asynchronous, even though they're I/O-based.